# Remove a lookup value in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have an entity called NDS which has a look up to account. Now, in the UI, I can click on the Lookup icon and click on another account record (Update) or click on the Remove button to remove the value.

How do I do the same functionality via code for the remove. I am writing a Plugin.

```
//Code to update
NDS["accountid"] = new EntityReference("Account", neworganizationid);
xrmService.Update(NDS)

//Code to remove
//??
```

The code to update works fine. It is the code to remove where it fails. I thought that the code to update would just work fine without any issues even with Remove, but I have an error message

Account With Id = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Does Not Exist

Any thoughts?

PS: I am new to MS CRM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as it's not an N:N relationship, you just need to do this:

```
NDS["accountid"] = null;
xrmService.Update(NDS);
```

From your error message I'm guessing you're doing this:

```
NDS["accountid"] = new EntityReference();
xrmService.Update(NDS);
```

which won't work.

And as a reminder, if it is an N:N relationship, you'll need to use the [Disassociate Request](http://mscrm-developer.blogspot.com/2008/09/delete-disassociate-many-to-many.html)

Comment: Daryl: Actually, I was reading the value of the field and it was coming back as 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000. So, my code was NDS["accountid"] = new EntityReference("Account", neworganizationid);

But your suggestion worked! 

Note my myself: Next time, try setting a value to NULL...will you? ;-)

Comment: Daryl: But the next time I open the record and my plugin runs, it is not even able to see the attribute accountid, i.e, NDS.Contains["accountid"] returns false. Any ideas?

Comment: @Kanini If NDS doesn't have an account, it will not be in the late bound attribute collection.